# Using jquery .ajax to retrieve records from mySQL DB

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am a mySQL noob, and have a slightly stupid question...

I am using jquery to send form to a php script which then stores the data in a mySQL database.  On another page in my app, I need to get all the values from one column of said mySQL DB, using jquery again (I assume I will also have to write another php script) so I can use the retrieved data.  I am very familiar with using POST or GET to send data, but all of a sudden realized I have no idea how to retrieve it in a way that it can be used by a jquery callback function.

By the way, I'm using php4.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you using PHP4?  Might want to mention that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for [json_encode()](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

Here is an example of using [PHP, JSON and AJAX](http://ditio.net/2008/07/17/php-json-and-javascript-usage/) that sends JSON to PHP.  [This tutorial](http://simpletutorials.com/?path=tutorials/javascript/simple_ajax) sends JSON data back.

By the way, are you using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) or similar Javascript framework?  If not, I'd highly recommend it as it can abstract a lot of the cross-browser differences and error-handling with the [ajax()](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax) call.  Here is an [example of .ajax() in action](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-ajaxjquery.html):

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'document.xml',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'xml',
    timeout: 1000,
    error: function(){
        alert('Error loading XML document');
    },
    success: function(xml){
        // do something with xml
    }
});
```

Now all that assumes you're using PHP 5.2+ (which is when json_encode()/json_decode() were addd).  If that's not the case you may have to use XML instead.

Here is an [introduction to Javascript and XML](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/JavaScript/JavaScript-and-XML/) and the [manual for the PHP XML parser](http://au.php.net/xml).  You are using jQuery so XML parsing gets a bit easier, see [this article](http://www.webmonkey.com/tutorial/Easy_XML_Consumption_using_jQuery?oldid=20032).

XML is more tedious to deal with (and the messages are slightly more verbose) but it's arguably safer.  For completeness it's worth pointing out the [security issues with JSON](http://directwebremoting.org/blog/joe/2007/03/05/json_is_not_as_safe_as_people_think_it_is.html).

Comment: I am using jquery, and I really like it...the .ajax call I am using is really simple, its just

$.ajax({
      url: "getID.php",
      success: function(data){ // do stuff }
});

but like i said, i dont have a new enough version of php to use so i cant use json_encode();